# How to unzip an archive during Eclipse plugin installation using p2 touchpoint instructions

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, unzip, p2

My current attempt is not working: in my_plugin/META-INF/p2.inf, I have:

instructions.install = unzip(source:${artifact}/browser.zip,target:${artifact});

No error occurs during installation, but the browser.zip archive is not unzipped.

What am I doing wrong?

Cheers.

**Edit**: more info: there actually are errors in the workspace log file:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.touchpoint.natives 4 0 2011-04-22 23:58:20.967
!MESSAGE org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.touchpoint.natives.actions.UnzipAction the files to be unzipped is not here

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.touchpoint.natives 4 0 2011-04-22 23:58:20.968
!MESSAGE org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.touchpoint.natives.actions.UnzipAction error unzipping zipfile: /Users/admin/sandbox/eclipse-dev/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/osgi.bundle,com.myplugin.test,1.0.0.201104211649/browser.zipdestination: osgi.bundle,com.myplugin.test,1.0.0.201104211649
```

How do I properly reference the path to my plugin in the unzip command?

Comment: ${artifact} always is the .jar file, how to unzip the a.jar/brower.zip?

Comment: my plugin is part of a feature, and in my feature.xml i've specified unpack=true for this plugin, and so the plugin jar is extracted into a directory. This is successful, I've confirmed.

I've actually got this working now:
instructions.install = unzip(source: ${artifact.location}/browser.zip, target:${artifact.location});

Comment: try to move the unzip action to 'configure' phase, instructions.configure=unzip

Comment: and I don't see the benefit of package browser.zip inside a bundle, why not put the files as the root files of your plug-in

Answer (score 1):

- Check "Unpack the plugin archive after the installation" on "Installed plugins" tab of the feature install unit.
- Move the *unzip* action to the **install** phase to the **configure** phase as
  [Kane](https://stackoverflow.com/users/390513/kane)  mentioned.

That worked for me